# SFML Project Running Perfectly in Codeblocks but Release EXE Giving Errors Even with all DLLs included

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml, static-linking, dynamic-linking

So I have this issue and I cannot seem to find a solution to it online. I am dynamically linking SFML following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcZFaiGFIMA) using the same exact versions of both Codeblocks and SFML. It works perfectly fine in the IDE but when I try to run the EXE file from the release folder (Yes, I do have all my SFML DLLs in the same folder) it gives 3 errors along the lines of:

`_ZSt4_throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz could not be located in sfml-graphics-2.dll`

I also tried linking it statically according to [this guide](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/start-cb.php), however this is worse since it doesn't even compile. It gives errors along the lines of:

`undefined reference to 'FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes'`

Honestly I am lost and out of ideas at this point. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: *"works perfectly fine in the IDE"* maybe it uses different set of dlls in this case? How did you obtain those dlls? Did you compile them properly using the same compiler that you are using to build your executable? Note that none of the common IDEs or build systems take the burden of tracking any dependencies of C++ projects on their shoulders so you always need to manually ensure code and binary compatibility.

Comment: I got them from the SFML website just as he did in that tutorial. So what you are saying in terms of the dependencies of dependencies, is that I have to obtain the DLLs of all the dependencies and manually link them too?

Comment: If it works fine in IDE but does not work outside of IDE then you most likely have two sets of libraries. To use dlls from their webside you need to make sure that they are compiled with the same compiler version that you are using.

Comment: By compiler you are referring to the "GCC..." thing that I keep coming across yes?

Comment: To gcc / mingw / clang / vc++ / ic++ / ghc++ or whatever compilers exists.